# Making a conclusion about a $\liminf $ of an increasing sequence of integers

Tags: limits, integers, limsup-and-liminf

I have a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers $\left\{ v_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}$
  for which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{v_{n}}=\infty$
  and $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{v_{n}}{n}=\infty$. I would like to show that no such sequence can exist. By using the converse of the limit comparison test on the fact that the $v_{n}$s are not reciprocal-summable, I obtain: $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{v_{n}}{n^{1+\delta}}=0,\textrm{ }\forall\delta>0$$

Is this sufficient to reach the desired contradiction? In other words, can I conclude that: 
$$0=\lim_{\delta\downarrow0}\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{v_{n}}{n^{1+\delta}}=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\lim_{\delta\downarrow0}\frac{v_{n}}{n^{1+\delta}}\right)=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{v_{n}}{n}=\infty$$

Or is there some arcane detail which prevents me from making this conclusion?

Comment: Just take $v_n=p_n$ ($n$th prime).

Comment: $v_n = n\log(n)$ for $n \ge 2$. (Divergent by integral test).

Comment: There is an interesting similar problem in the Monthly this month, Problem 12004; https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.124.8.754